# 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'spreadsheets'

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets-api

This is my first time working with google sheets api. So, I'm trying to bold the first row of a google sheet. But I get the error **'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'spreadsheets'** while doing so. I have mentioned the code below. Please point out what am I doing wrong.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentials.json",scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("SheetsAPI Practice").sheet1

req = { "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 1
        },
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
                "textFormat": {
                    "bold": True        
                }
            }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold"
    }
}

sheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=sheet.id,body=req).execute()
```

The error occurred on this line -

> sheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=sheet.id,body=req).execute()

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Please check the comment section of your answer. I really appreciate your such concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to use the method of batchUpdate in Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In gspread, there are no method of `spreadsheets()` in `client.open("SheetsAPI Practice").sheet1`. In your script, you are trying to use the method of googleapis of python with gspread. The reason of error message is this.
- The gspread has the method for using batchUpdate in Sheets API. So you can use this, when `client = gspread.authorize(creds)` can be used for the Google Spreadsheet you want to use.
- Your request body is required to be modified. When you use `req` to the batchUpdate method, please put in the array like `{"requests": [req]}`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
sheet = client.open("SheetsAPI Practice").sheet1

req = { "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 1
        },
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
                "textFormat": {
                    "bold": True
                }
            }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold"
    }
}

sheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=sheet.id,body=req).execute()
```

To:

```
spreadsheet = client.open("SheetsAPI Practice")
req = {
    "requests": [
      {
          "repeatCell": {
              "range": {
                  "sheetId": 0,
                  "startRowIndex": 0,
                  "endRowIndex": 1
              },
              "cell": {
                  "userEnteredFormat": {
                      "textFormat": {
                          "bold": True
                      }
                  }
              },
              "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold"
          }
      }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(req)
```

- When this modified script is run, the texts of 1st row become the bold.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that the Google Spreadsheet can be used by the service account. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain so nicely. Whatever you said is actually correct. However, when I ran the modified version of yours, it gave an error like this - **string indices must be integers**. So then I sent the parameter as a list like this - `spreadsheet.batch_update([req])`. This time it gave me an error like this - **KeyError: 'range'**. It would be a big help if you could point out the problem and what should I do to fix it.

Comment: Ah I apologize! Your answer actually did the work. The error occurred because I had the first sheet open like this sheet = client.open("SheetsAPI Practice").sheet1. But I was supposed to open it like you showed - spreadsheet = client.open("SheetsAPI Practice"). And then mention the sheetId in the request body. Thank you so much @Tanaike

Comment: @Wall-E Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.